# Elasticsearch 5 variance in keyword ot text field

Tags: elasticsearch

I using elasticsearch 5, I know how to get variance of number field but I do not know how to get variance of keyword or text field,
Someone can help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked it, and my conclusion is that elasticsearch can't do that, you need to this you're own.